# Пример реализации перегрузки конструкторов

Tags: java

Мне дали домашнее задание, реализовать пример перегрузки конструктора, правильно я сделал?

```
public class Human {

        private String name;
        private String surname;
        private int age;
        private String profession;
        private boolean car;

        public Person(String name, String surname) {
           this.name = name;
           this.surname = surname;
        }

        public Human(String name, String surname, int age){
            this.name = name;
            this.surname = surname;
            this.age = age;
        }

        public Human(String name, String surname, int age, String profession, boolean car){
            this.name = name;
            this.surname = surname;
            this.age = age;
            this.profession = profession;
            this.car = car;
        }
}


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Human p1 = new Human("Иван", "Иванов");
        Human p2 = new Human("Федя", "Федоров", 43);
        Human p3 = new Human("Метя", "Метьков", 26, "Слесарь", true);

    }
}
```

Comment: код не скомпилируется

Comment: @StrangerintheQ скомпилировался

Comment: значит в ide у Вас другой код, тут класс `Human` а конструктор `Person`

Comment: @StrangerintheQ а всё увидел, извините :)

Comment: Чтобы не дублировался код, можно из конструктора с меньшим числом аргументов вызывать конструктор с бОльшим их числом. В вашем случае первый контср будет таким: this(name, surname, 0);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы реализовали перегрузку конструкторов.

Перегрузка методов примерно тоже самое, только там создаётся несколько методов с одним именем, но разной сигнатурой.

К примеру:

```
public setData(String name, String surname) {
   this.name = name;
   this.surname = surname;
}

public setData(String name) {
   this.name = name;
}
```

Comment: Извините, увидел и изменил, мне нужно было реализовать пример перегрузки конструктора, он правильный?

Comment: @MikeMclaren вполне.

Comment: @Suvitruf тут класс `Human` а конструктор `Person` :)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ну, это косяк при копировании, вероятно. Концептуально то всё верно.

Comment: @Suvitruf Вам ли не знать как докопаются до этого в универе =)

Comment: Я изменил, извините :)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ у нас в своё время не докапывались до таких мелочей, если студент мог всё объяснить )

Comment: @MikeMclaren ничего ничего =)